# undefined local variable or method `article_params' for #<ArticlesController:0x007ff45cebd680>

Tags: ruby

i'm having problems with my page I created .the message i get is above.this is my articles controller.rb page code.learning ruby and the challenges it brings.i'm stuck in this section. And i've been having issues with section.once i post up my code.i don't know if i messed up my codes  or something like that.

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

```
def index
@articles = Article.all
end

  def new
 @article =Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.new(article_params[:id])
  end



def create
   @article =Article.new(article_params)
   if@article.save
     flash[:notice] = "Article was successfully created"
   redirect_to article_path(@article)
     else
     render 'new'
   end
   end





 def update
      @article =Article.find(params[:id])
      if@article.update
        flash[:notice] = "Article was successfully updated"
        redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
    render 'edit'



 end
end

def show



 @article =Article.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

and this is the error page undefined local variable or method `article_params' for #

Extracted source (around line #12):
10
11
12
13
14
15

def edit
    @article = Article.new(article_params[:id])
  end

```
i get on ruby rails
```

Comment: You didn't define the method `article_params` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yip, as Alfie said above, you're missing your article_params. 
In rails 4 (which I assume is what you're using) there is the concept of strong paramaters, which is a way of only allowing the fields you're expecting through.

Depending on what fields are in your "article"  object, you need to add something like this:

```
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end
```

Note, you'll need to adjust it to suit whatever your actual fields are.

Also, might be a copy & paste error, but it's a good idea to get into the habit of indenting your code correctly!  Good luck with getting the codes to work :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `article_params` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass article_params to update.

```
def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update(article_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Article was successfully updated'
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      redirect 'edit'
    end
  end
```